# Which is more efficient, appending a one-character string or a char?

Tags: c#

In terms of performance, is there any difference in doing:
`stringX + 'y'` vs `stringX + "y"`?

If there is a difference, why is there?

My question is pertaining mainly to C#.

Comment: Why don't you test it before you ask?

Comment: `StringBuilder`

Comment: Your time is probably better spent thinking about other issues. Things like this will never be your biggest bottleneck and if you really want to optimize this, optimize for readability, not performance.

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves: if he tested it before asking, he wouldn't need to ask it

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden, I know that's the case. I was asking from an academic perspective out of curiosity

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I did test it, but my results were inconclusive and gave rather inconsistent results. My test methodology might have been wrong, but I did make an attempt.

Comment: @JamesHughes: i recommend using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). Compile in release and then start the benchmark-test-app not in visual studio but the exe. This is the summary of a test: `Method Mean StdDev
Version 1: 17.0179 ns 0.1315 ns
Version 2:  17.1224 ns 0.3225 ns`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's absolutely no difference between the two. For example if you have the following two functions:

```
static string Method1()
{
    var stringX = "abc";
    var res = stringX + 'y';
    return res;
}

static string Method2()
{
    var stringX = "abc";
    var res = stringX + "y";
    return res;
}
```

Here's the corresponding IL that gets emitted by the C# compiler (built in Release mode):

```
.method private hidebysig static string Method1 () cil managed 
{
    IL_0000: ldstr "abc"
    IL_0005: ldstr "y"
    IL_000a: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,  string)
    IL_000f: ret
}

.method private hidebysig static string Method2 () cil managed 
{
    IL_0000: ldstr "abc"
    IL_0005: ldstr "y"
    IL_000a: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,  string)
    IL_000f: ret
}
```

The compiler is intelligent enough to emit the proper IL for the highly unusual `stringX + 'y'` construct.